# Showing a progress dialog in Android app

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, progressdialog

I want to use a progress dialog in an activity named `myActivity`.
I launch it from a method in the activity:

```java
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.this, "", "loading ...");
```

but nothing appears. Why?

I've also tried this line:

```java
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.this, "", "loading ...",true);
```

with the same result.

Comment: did you try to add an actual title ? is there any kind of crash ?

Comment: I try just even title...but the application runs without crash!

Comment: do you dismiss it at some point ? in what thread are you ? don't you have anything in the logs ?

Comment: Are you doing this prior to working on the UI thread, and dismissing it immediately afterward? If so, the thread won't update with the Dialog until roughly the same time it's dismissed. If that's the case, move your work to an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 3):

Just this

```
//Declare progressDialog before so you can use .hide() later!
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add runnable thread into your code

Example: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/progressdialog

or see this example code

```
progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (progressDialog.getProgress() <= progressDialog.getMax()) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                handle.sendMessage(handle.obtainMessage());
            if (progressDialog.getProgress() == progressDialog.getMax()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}).start();
```